# Android copy database from internal to external storage

Tags: android, database

I'm trying to copy my existing databases from my Internal to External Storage,but I have a little problem. It says that `the file does not exist`. Here is what I'm using actually :

to copy files from internal to external storage :

```
    private void copyFile(String src, String dst) throws IOException{
    FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();
    try
    {
        inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (inChannel != null)
            inChannel.close();
        if (outChannel != null)
            outChannel.close();
    }
}
```

and I'm using it like this :

```
copyFile("/data/data/com.example.test/databases/database.sqlite","/sdcard/.Example/Data/database.sqlite");
```

but it's not working and I'm pretty sure that the database in internal storage is there.

If I set as a destination folder in `copyFile` `"/sdcard/.Example/Data/"` it's creating file `Data` in `.Example`.

Any suggestions what I'm missing?

Answer (score 8):

Use this to copy your database to sdcard.

```
public void copyFile()
    {
        try 
        {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd.canWrite()) 
            {
                String currentDBPath = "\\data\\your.package.name\\databases\\dabase_name";
                String backupDBPath = "database_name";
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                }
                if(bool == true)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Backup Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    bool = false;
                }
            }               
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("Settings Backup", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your currentDB path didn't work for me. This worked: "/data/my.package.name/databases/mydbName.db"

Comment: "if(bool == true)" ? I think there is an initialization missing somewhere. Best guess is you want to check "transferFrom" long response against the size of  the original db, or check to see if its greater than 1 see: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom(java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel, long, long)

Answer (score 6):

If you don't know your application path then you can use this:

```
//for without "Resource leak: '<unassigned Closeable value>' is never closed" warning, something like this
public void copyAppDbToDownloadFolder() throws IOException {
    try {
        String currDate = Constants.APP_DATE_SHORT_FORMAT.format(new Date());
        File backupDB = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), DbContract.DATABASE_BUCKUP_NAME + currDate + ".db");
        File currentDB = appCon.getDatabasePath(DbContract.DATABASE_NAME);
        if (currentDB.exists()) {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(currentDB);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(backupDB);
            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(fis.getChannel(), 0, fis.getChannel().size());
            // or fis.getChannel().transferTo(0, fis.getChannel().size(), fos.getChannel());
            fis.close();
            fos.close();
            Log.i("Database successfully", " copied to download folder");
            return true;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Copying Database", "fail, reason:", e);
    }
}
```

Or if you need copy database to public "Download" folder then you can use this:

```
public void copyAppDbToDownloadFolder() throws IOException {
    try {
        File backupDB = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "toDatabaseName"); // for example "my_data_backup.db"
        File currentDB = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("databaseName"); //databaseName=your current application database name, for example "my_data.db"
        if (currentDB.exists()) {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(currentDB);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(backupDB);
            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(fis.getChannel(), 0, fis.getChannel().size());
            // or fis.getChannel().transferTo(0, fis.getChannel().size(), fos.getChannel());
            fis.close();
            fos.close();
            Log.i("Database successfully", " copied to download folder");
            return true;
        } else Log.i("Copying Database", " fail, database not found");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Copying Database", "fail, reason:", e);
    }
}
```

This is working perfectly on my Nexus 4 device.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the use of this method:

```
public static boolean copyFile(String from, String to) {
    boolean result = false;
    try{
        File dir = new File(to.substring(0, to.lastIndexOf('/')));
        dir.mkdirs();
        File tof = new File(dir, to.substring(to.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
        int byteread;
        File oldfile = new File(from);
        if(oldfile.exists()){
            InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(from);
            FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(tof);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while((byteread = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                fs.write(buffer, 0, byteread);
            }
            inStream.close();
            fs.close();
        }
        result = true;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("copyFile", "Error copying file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

which would be called in this way: knowing the package of your application and the name of the file or database saved in internal storage, indicate the source and destination of the file to be copied:

```
//Obtiene ruta de base de datos origen.
String pathDB = getDatabasePath(NOMBRE_DATABASE).toString();
//Copia base de datos a destino definido.
copyFile(pathDB, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Android/data/" + getPackageName() + "/" + <nombre archivo destino>);
```

Do not forget to add permission `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` into your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android: name = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

With this method you can copy files or databases to external storage:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

#### *Important

to use the ** [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ** permission on devices with operating systems greater than ** [Android 6.0](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ** (which is implicitly also `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`) must be manually requested:

```
//Verifica permisos para Android 6.0+
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){

     checkExternalStoragePermission();
}
```

Using this method:

```
private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Yes, I've already did this. Actually I've noticed that the file is copied, but it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

This program can copy a database named "Your Database Name" from internal storage of an android app into external storage.It creates a folder named "Folder Name" and then copy the database into a file named "Backup Database Name" inside that folder

1.This program is compatible with android marshmallow
2.As MediaScannerConnection is used,you can immediately copy the backup file from a computer with windows operating system without restarting your system
3.If "Folder Name" doesn't exists it will create it automatically
4.If your specified backup file name already exists,it will show a alert dialog

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
    if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 5);
    }
    else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},5);
    }
}
else{
    final File backupDb=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+File.separator+"<Folder Name>"+File.separator+"<Backup Database Name>");
    final File currentDB = new File(String.valueOf(getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("<Your Database Name>")));
    if(backupDb.exists()){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Alert")
                .setMessage("File already exists.Do you want to replace it")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if(!new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+File.separator+"<Folder Name>").canWrite()) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to write into external storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            if(!currentDB.exists()){
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Database doesn't exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else{
                                try {
                                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDb).getChannel();
                                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                                    src.close();
                                    dst.close();
                                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), new String[]{backupDb.toString()}, null, null);
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Database successfully copied to external storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    editText.setText(null);
                                }catch(Exception e){
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got exception" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter another name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(R.drawable.alert);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
    else{
        new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+File.separator+"<Folder Name>").mkdir();
        if(!new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+File.separator+"<Folder Name>").canWrite()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to write into external storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            if(!currentDB.exists()){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Database doesn't exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                try {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDb).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), new String[]{backupDb.toString()}, null, null);
                    editText.setText(null);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Database successfully copied to external storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got exception" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

"Your Database Name" -> Database internal to your application
"Backup Database Name" -> File in which you want to copy the database
"Folder Name" -> The folder in which backup database is to be stored