# View my applications db in mobile for HTC one

Tags: android, operating-system, root

I followed this link (http://www.htcdev.com/bootloader/) to unlock my HTC one mobile. I thought that unlocking my mobile will gain me db access of my application in that mobile. But I cannot find the db file of my app as I see for emulator.

Am I assuming correct or missing something. Is rooting is the only way for gaining access to my app db ?

Comment: no ... you can copy your db to non private storage(sd card, etc.) from your app and then you'll able to do something with it (copy to PC, use from other app, etc.)

Comment: I cant even view my db in unlocked mobile. How do I copy it ?

Comment: FSM save us!!!! could you at least try to search internet by yourself?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066682/android-copy-database-from-internal-to-external-storage