# sending sqlite data to another android device

Tags: android

I was working on android app, I used sqlite database to store data.
I finished my app now, in my app I want the user to save data on his device and send it to another device to can use this data.
I wonder if I could sending sqlite database files with the app to another device

Comment: there can be many ways. You can export your db into a `.db` file and send it to other devices using [beam](https://developer.android.com/training/beam-files/send-files.html) function, bluetooth, or wifi-direct. You can even use email, text, etc by read the buffer from `.db` file and send it as plain text, read it from another device and save it back to `.db` file.

Answer (score 0):

The database file is located under `/data/data<your package name>/databases` and it's readable from by your app only.

To make it available to other apps and the user you can copy it to the sdcard or internal storage. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066682/android-copy-database-from-internal-to-external-storage) for code sample.

Another approach would be to export the data in a more readable format (ex. csv) to the sdcard/internal memory and import the file via the app on another device.